# How to convert a black and white image into coordinates?

Tags: raspberry-pi

I'm trying to design a vertical plotter and it has to be wireless.

My main idea was to take a simple black and white image and convert it into coordinates. These could then be passed through a program which I will write to control the plotter.

However, I can't seem to find any program or site which can convert. What I'm hoping for is a program or site which can take the image and convert every black part into a series or points which would be taken as a coordinates (with the bottom left corner as (0,0)).

If there is anything out there please let me know. If you have any other idea of how to do this please suggest them to me and I'll try to work it out myself before asking for further clarification. Thank you.

Comment: What did you already try?

Comment: What do you mean with coordinates? The row and column of every black point is in principle the coordinate of that pixel. Do you want a list of all the black pixel points. Please give an example of an input image and what you would like as an output. I am not sure about the vertical plotter but for 2D plotters (or actually 3D printing), slicers are used to convert an image to coordinates or Gcode, maybe that helps?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest **ImageMagick** which is included in most Linux distros and is available for macOS and Windows.

Let's start with this image, which is 6x2 - I have enlarged it and put a red stroke around the edge so you can see it and its extent on StackOverflow's white background:

[image]

So, it doesn't matter if it is JPEG, BMP, TIFF, PNG, GIF as ImageMagick can read everything. If I threshold it at 50% to make sure it consists only of pure black and white and make the output 8-bit and text, you can easily see the black pixels and their coordinates (in the first column):

```
convert image.png -threshold 50% -depth 8 txt:
```

**Sample Output**

```
# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 6,2,65535,srgb
0,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
1,0: (65535,65535,65535)  #FFFFFF  white
2,0: (65535,65535,65535)  #FFFFFF  white
3,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
4,0: (65535,65535,65535)  #FFFFFF  white
5,0: (65535,65535,65535)  #FFFFFF  white
0,1: (65535,65535,65535)  #FFFFFF  white
1,1: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
2,1: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
3,1: (65535,65535,65535)  #FFFFFF  white
4,1: (65535,65535,65535)  #FFFFFF  white
5,1: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
```

So, for an easy way to see just the black pixels, strip everything else out:

```
convert start.png -threshold 50% -depth 8 txt: | grep black
```

**Sample Output**

```
0,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
3,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
1,1: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
2,1: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
5,1: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
```

You can now probably see that the 0,0 coordinate is top-left, rather than the bottom-left you asked for, so let's flip the image first:

```
convert start.png -threshold 50% -depth 8 -flip txt: | grep black
```

**Sample Output**

```
1,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
2,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
5,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
0,1: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
3,1: (0,0,0)  #000000  black
```

So, if you just want the coordinates, filter and tidy up with `awk`:

```
convert start.png -threshold 50% -depth 8 -flip txt: | awk -F: '/black/{print $1}'
```

**Sample Output**

```
1,0
2,0
5,0
0,1
3,1
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. Really helped me along. For some reason grep doesn't work for me. Any idea why not or any other solution to filtering?

Comment: It's hard to debug when all I know is *"It didn't work"*. Can you click `edit` under your original question and in some additional info, such as what command you entered, what output and what error messages you got and I'll have a look for you.

Answer (score 1):

Mark Setchell has a good way to do that in Imagemagick. I would just like to show an alternate method. Rather than using txt: to output the long text, you can use sparse-color to just get the coordinates and color. (There is a slight bug in the current IM 6.9.9.33, so I will use IM 7 magick in place of convert. So using the same image (without flipping, so 0,0 is still at the top left):

```
magick image.png sparse-color:
0,0,gray(0) 1,0,gray(255) 2,0,gray(255) 3,0,gray(0) 4,0,gray(255) 5,0,gray(255) 0,1,gray(255) 1,1,gray(0) 2,1,gray(0) 3,1,gray(255) 4,1,gray(255) 5,1,gray(0)
```

or

```
magick image.png sparse-color:  | tr " " "\n"
0,0,gray(0)
1,0,gray(255)
2,0,gray(255)
3,0,gray(0)
4,0,gray(255)
5,0,gray(255)
0,1,gray(255)
1,1,gray(0)
2,1,gray(0)
3,1,gray(255)
4,1,gray(255)
5,1,gray(0)
```

Or filter with grep for gray(0) and use awk to get the first two comma separated values.

```
magick image.png sparse-color:  | tr " " "\n" | grep "gray(0)" | awk -F, '{print $1","$2}'
0,0
3,0
1,1
2,1
5,1
```