# How to filter 4 different colours on ImageMagick?

Tags: imagemagick

I'm using ImageMagick to transform an image into x and y cartesian co-ordinates. The code that I am using in the command line does fine to make all the lines appear as fully black and the blank spaces appear as fully white. Is there a way to also filter for more colours? For example, if the image consists of multiple colours, is there a way to make all the red-type colours fully red, all the blue-type colours fully blue and the other non-white colours as black? Then the background would just be seen as fully white (most images I am using as a picture on a white background). The command line text is:

convert "imagename".png -white-threshold 50% -black-threshold 50% txt:

Using Mark Setchell's code from below, I tried to convert this basic image that I created using paint to test the abilities of IM.

[image]

I edited the code slightly so that the background fill would be white instead of black as such;

```
convert q.png -write MPR:orig -delete 0 -compose lighten ^ ( MPR:orig -fuzz 10% -fill red  -opaque red  -fill white +opaque red  ) ^ ( MPR:orig -fuzz 10% -fill blue -opaque blue -fill white +opaque blue ) -composite ^ ( MPR:orig -fuzz 10% -fill lime -opaque lime -fill white +opaque lime ) -composite ^ f.png
```

However, the entire image just shows white. Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you want, but maybe this will get us closer. So, we start with this:

[image]

And we then do this, which says *"make anything within 10% of red into solid red, anything within 25% of blue into solid blue, and so on"*:

```
convert start.png  -fuzz 10%  \
   -fill red   -opaque red    \
   -fuzz 25%                  \
   -fill blue  -opaque blue   \
   -fill lime  -opaque lime   \
   -fill white -opaque white result.png
```

[image]

---

Or maybe more like this:

```
convert start.png -write MPR:orig -delete 0 -compose lighten \
   \( MPR:orig -fuzz 10% -fill red  -opaque red  -fill black +opaque red \) \
   \( MPR:orig -fuzz 20% -fill blue -opaque blue -fill black +opaque blue \) -composite \
   \( MPR:orig -fuzz 30% -fill lime -opaque lime -fill black +opaque lime \) -composite \
   result.png
```

[image]

That says... *"Take the original image and make a copy in the Magick Persistent Register called `orig` then delete the original. Set the blending mode to select the lightest pixel at each location for any future `composite` commands. Now make a new layer, fill it with the original image, make anything within 10% of red into solid red **and make anything else black**. Now do the same for colours within 20% of blue and blend taking the lighter layer - so the blues and reds show instead of the blacks which will always be darkest. Do the same again for lime - which is how **ImageMagick** refers to pure green.""*

Note how the green is larger than the blue which, in turn, is larger than the red because of the differing amounts of fuzz I applied - i.e. 30%, 20% 10%.

---

I *think* that looks like this with Windows-style quoting:

```
convert start.png -write MPR:orig -delete 0 -compose lighten ^
( MPR:orig -fuzz 10% -fill red  -opaque red  -fill black +opaque red  ) ^
( MPR:orig -fuzz 20% -fill blue -opaque blue -fill black +opaque blue ) -composite ^
( MPR:orig -fuzz 30% -fill lime -opaque lime -fill black +opaque lime ) -composite ^
result.png
```

Comment: Ah mate this is perfect. Thank you so much. Exactly what I needed.

Comment: Cool - good luck with your project! Remember questions (and answers) are free, so come back and ask a new question if you get stuck.

Comment: Hi there. Small issue. I tried to run your code but for some reason only the green section was showing. Any insight as to why?

Comment: Which code example did you use? Are you using Windows, Linux or mac?

Comment: Same as the answer to your previous question here... https://stackoverflow.com/q/48226565/2836621  I don't know what actual command you ran, nor which image you used, nor which version of ImageMagick you used, nor what OS you are using, nor what the error messages nor results were so it is impossible to debug. Please click `edit` under your question and add in all the details and I will do my very best to work out the problem.

Comment: Hi. I used the image and code that you provided in your answer. I'm using Windows 7 and running IM version 7.0.7 Q8 (64 Bit)

Comment: Aha, ok. Quoting is different in Windows. I *think* there are two differences. 1) The opening and closing parentheses do not need a backslash in front of them on Windows, so remove them. 2) The continuation character at the end of the line is a caret (`^`) in Windows, rather than a backslash, so replace all the backslashes at the ends of lines with carets.

Comment: Oh, the `%` may need a caret (`^`) in front too! Or maybe a second percent sign, i.e. `%%`

Comment: Also V7 uses magick not convert. Depending on how you setup Imagemagick convert should still work but is I believe actually using a V6.9 version of Imagemagick.

Comment: Please report back whatever you find about Windows quoting and I will correct/update the answer accordingly so other folks can see the correct version.

Comment: Hey again. The quoting and everything is working fine but I am having some issues. I made an image of just some blobs of colours (explained more in the edit). When I try to run the code only the red parts show. Any help?

Comment: You have filled all the areas surrounding each blob with white and then at each point in the image you have chosen the lightest colour so you will get white everywhere. Go back to my code, and then add this in just before the final output image in order to make black into white `... -fill white -opaque black result.png`