# append two gifs side-by-side with ImageMagick on Windows

Tags: windows, imagemagick

On Linux (Ubuntu), I was able to append two animated gifs (same sizes, same number of frames) with this command:

```
convert file1.gif'[0]' -coalesce \\( file2.gif'[0]' -coalesce \\) \\
          +append -channel A -evaluate set 0 +channel \\
          file1.gif -coalesce -delete 0 \\
          null: \\( file2.gif -coalesce \\) \\
          -gravity East -layers Composite output.gif
```

You can also find this command here: [Animation Modifications](https://github.com/ImageMagick/usage-markdown/blob/master/anim_mods/index.md).

On Windows this command does not work. It generates errors:

```
convert torusEnlargingSpheres3.gif'[0]' -coalesce \\( torusEnlargingSpheres6.gif'[0]' -coalesce \\) +append -channel A -evaluate set 0 +channel torusEnlargingSpheres3.gif -coalesce -delete 0 null:: \\( torusEnlargingSpheres6.gif -coalesce \\) -gravity East -layers Composite output.gif

convert.exe: UnableToOpenBlob `torusEnlargingSpheres3.gif'[0]'': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2701.
convert.exe: NoDecodeDelegateForThisImageFormat `GIF'[0]'' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/504.
convert.exe: UnableToOpenBlob `\\(': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2701.
convert.exe: NoDecodeDelegateForThisImageFormat `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/504.
convert.exe: UnableToOpenBlob `torusEnlargingSpheres6.gif'[0']': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2701.
convert.exe: NoDecodeDelegateForThisImageFormat `GIF'[0']' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/504.
convert.exe: UnableToOpenBlob `\\)': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2701.
convert.exe: NoDecodeDelegateForThisImageFormat `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/504.
convert.exe: UnableToOpenBlob `\\(': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2701.
convert.exe: NoDecodeDelegateForThisImageFormat `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/504.
convert.exe: UnableToOpenBlob `\\)': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2701.
convert.exe: NoDecodeDelegateForThisImageFormat `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/504.
```

What should I change in order to use this command on Windows ?

This command does not generate errors but it does not append the images:

```
convert file1.gif"[0]" -coalesce ^( file2.gif"[0]" -coalesce ^) +append -channel A -evaluate set 0 +channel file1.gif -coalesce -delete 0 null:: ^( file2.gif -coalesce ^) -gravity East -layers Composite output.gif
```

Comment: I think you need to replace double slashes, where acting as line continuation characters, with carets (`^`). And remove double backslashes before opening and closing parentheses. And replace single quotes with double quotes.

Comment: @MarkSetchell  Thanks. I've tried that, unsuccessful.

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you tried, thank you. Also look at bottom of this answer... https://stackoverflow.com/a/49358428/2836621

Comment: @MarkSetchell I've just edited. Thanks for the link.

Comment: I don't think you need carets before parentheses. Sorry, I only have limited Windows knowledge.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Yes, I can remove them, this is the same.

Comment: The `null::` looks suspicious, maybe. It has two colons suddenly and I think it is a reserved word in Windows, so maybe put it in double quotes so Windows doesn't see it.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks. The double colon is an error, it should be a single one. But that does not work, even with the quotes.

Comment: I'll try and make an answer with a list of rules that we can update as we learn more and then it will become useful as a reference for others... and myself!

Comment: The command you currently have at the bottom of your question works fine for me in Windows XP.

Comment: @MarkSetchell !!!! Weird ! I'm using Windows 7. Maybe the version of ImageMagick is also involved ?

Comment: I have `Version: ImageMagick 6.9.7-1 Q16 x64 2016-12-31` (this is given by `convert -version`)

Comment: I think `::` introduces a comment in Windows, you can try `:: hello` and it doesn't generate any errors. I am using v7+

Comment: I've just tried `ImageMagick 7.0.7-24 Q16 x64 2018-02-25`. Doesn't work :-(

Comment: I presume you are using `CMD.EXE` not Powershell?

Comment: I am kind of stuck. Please try simplifying the command. 1) Remove everything after `-append` and then add an output filename and check it. 2) Try removing everything between `-channel` and `+channel`.

Comment: I did a similar thing before by the way... https://stackoverflow.com/a/30932152/2836621

Comment: Yes, I've just adapted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30927367/imagemagick-making-2-gifs-into-side-by-side-gifs-using-im-convert/30932152#30932152 to Windows. It works. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably simulate the "+append" with something like this...

Read in the file1 GIF, coalesce, and set its page geometry to extend it to double its width to the right. Coalesce again to create that additional canvas area.

Then include the "null:" to separate the file1 frames from the file2 frames.

Then read in the file2 GIF and coalesce it.

Finish by setting the gravity to east and using "-layers composite" to composite each file2 frame over the extended area of its partner file1 frame. Set the delay and "-loop 0", and name the output file.

A command to do that would look something like this...

```
convert ( file1.gif -coalesce -set page %[fx:w*2]x%[h]+0+0 -coalesce ) ^
   null: ( file2.gif -coalesce ) -gravity east -layers composite ^
   -set delay 20 -loop 0 result.gif
```

To use a command like this in a BAT script, make the single percent signs "%" into doubles "%%".

Comment: What do we have to change to append vertically ? `0+0%[fx:w*2]x%[h]` and `gravity south`?

Comment: Nope... I didn't find how to append vertically. Any idea please ?

Comment: You can set the page geometry so the "file1.gif" frames are doubled in height by using "-set page %[h]x%[fx:h*2]+0+0 -coalesce". Then using "-gravity south" and "-layers composite" should composite the "file2.gif" frames over the extended lower area "file1.gif" frames. The result would be like "-append" vertically.

Comment: Thanks. It works. But isn't it rather `%[w]x%[fx:h*2]+0+0` instead of `%[h]x%[fx:h*2]+0+0` ? (In my case width=height so there's no difference).

Comment: Yes. My mistake. The "w" is the width and the "h" is the height in an FX expression.

Answer (score 3):

Quoting is different on Windows from Unix. Here are some ideas on how to convert from Linux quoting to Window quoting. Note that most online ImageMagick examples are given with Linux style quoting, so this will be especially relevant to any Windows users.

---

**1. Line Continuation**

On Linux, the backslash is used as a line continuation character, but Windows uses a caret (`^`), so this (Linux):

```
convert image.png image.png \
   +append result.png
```

becomes this (Windows):

```
convert image.png image.png ^
    +append result.png
```

---

**2. Replace single quotes with double quotes**

On Linux, parameters can be quoted in single quotes, but on Windows, double quotes are required, so this (Linux):

```
convert 'image with spaces.png' info:
```

becomes this (Windows):

```
convert "image with spaces.png" info:
```

---

**3. Some characters need escaping removed when going to Windows**

On Linux, some characters need escaping by preceding them with backslashes, such as `(`, `)`, `!`  but this is unnecessary on Windows, so this (Linux):

```
convert image.png \( image.png -negate \) +append result.png
```

becomes this (Windows):

```
convert image.png ( image.png -negate ) +append result.png
```

---

**4. Double up percent signs**

Double up percent signs when going from Linux to Windows, so this (Linux):

```
convert xc:"gray(128)" -depth 8 -threshold 51% txt:
```

becomes this (Windows):

```
convert xc:"gray(128)" -depth 8 -threshold 51%% txt:
```

---

**5. Some characters need escaping added when going to Windows**

Some characters need a caret adding before them to escape them when moving to Windows, for example `|`, `&`, `>` and `<`, so this (Linux):

```
convert image.png -resize 1024x768\> result.png
```

becomes this (Windows):

```
convert image.png -resize 1024x768^> result.png
```

---

**6. Watch out for comments**

The hash sign (`#`) introduces comments in Linux, and these are probably best removed and placed elsewhere, so this (Linux):

```
convert input.png -auto-level result.png    # comment
```

could become either of these (Windows):

```
convert input.png -auto-level result.png
convert input.png -auto-level result.png    :: comment
```

---

If you are aware of any other cases, or that any of mine are incorrect, or could be better explained, please let me know via a comment and I will try to keep the list correct as a reference for other folk.

Answer (score 1):

Still I don't know how to fix the command. Let me provide the [Linux solution given here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30927367/imagemagick-making-2-gifs-into-side-by-side-gifs-using-im-convert/30932152#30932152) for Windows.

Here it is:

1) separate frames of `file1.gif` in files `a-0001.gif, ...`:

```
convert file1.gif -coalesce a-%04d.gif
```

2) separate frames of `file2.gif` in files `aa-0001.gif, ...`:

```
convert file2.gif -coalesce aa-%04d.gif
```

3) append frames side-by-side (using `%~nxf` to get a relative path - important):

```
for /r %f in (a-*.gif) do convert %f a%~nxf +append %f
```

4) join the appended frames:

```
convert -loop 0 -delay 20 a-*.gif result.gif
```

[image]