# Making a path for Fourier transform drawing

Tags: javascript, image, sorting

I'm currently trying to write a tiny JavaScript code that draws any picture with epicycles using the Fourier transform. The program takes in a list of coordinates of a path that is going to be drawn. For example, the list could be

```
[{x:123, y: 1}, {x:174, y:18}, {x:183, 281}...]
```

and the program will then connect those points using epicycles. The program itself works as expected, however, I am having a difficult time actually getting the coordinates of a given picture.

The picture below is the one that I am trying to get the coordinates of. [image]

I have "successfully" managed to extract all the coordinates of the black points in the picture above using ImageMagick as described in Mark Setchell's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48226565/how-to-convert-a-black-and-white-image-into-coordinates). When my program tries to draw the picture the outcome looks like this:

[image]

which is not exactly what I want since I just want to draw the outline. The problem here is that ImageMagick "reads" the pixels from left to right while working its way down, meaning that the coordinates that I get are in the wrong order. To clarify, let's look at the picture below:

```
A -- B
         The coordinates are in the order A, B, C, D. The program will draw a line from A to B, from B to C and from C to D. This is not desired.  
C -- D

A -- B
     | The coordinates are in the order A, B, C, D. The program till draw a line from A to B, from B to C and from C to D. This is desired. 
D -- C
```

Right now the coordinates are in the undesired form, as seen in the topmost picture. This means that the program will draw zigzags. I want to somehow get the coordinates of my picture so that they are in the right order so that the program will draw along the outline and not draw zigzags. Here are my possible solutions that I have come up with so far:

1. Order the list of coordinates so that they are in the right order. This might involve checking distances between points and ordering all the points such that two points lie besides each other if the distance between them is as small as possible.
2. Use a SVG image and extract all the points of a path in to a list like `[{x:x_1, y:y_1}, {x:x_2, y:y_2}...]`
3. Write a drawing program such that when I trace an image with my mouse, the coordinates of my mouse get pushed into a list.

I have honestly no idea how to implement 1. and 2. and option 3. seems like a bad way to tackle such a problem. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that the co-ordinates that your providing has co-ordinates of every pixel not only edge, so it traces pixel thats why you get zig zag, its not about patter.
i would suggest convert your image to only edges using edge detection and then extract the co-ordinates.